# why should I use @Inject annotation? (android)

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    class DataRepository @Inject constructor(private val dataDao: DataDao) { }

    class DataRepository constructor(private val dataDao: DataDao) { }
```

I don't know what's diffence between two classes.
Can any one tell me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is - `@Inject` is an annotation used by Dagger (or Koin), and it will automatically create the `DataRepository` class given that a `DataDao` is provided (or bound).

The other one is just a regular constructor.

You can still manually instantiate classes by calling their inject constructors by hand, although - when using a DI framework (dependency injection) there is no need to, that's what DI is for. To construct and instantiate things for you